# Getting PHPUnit tests to work in Eclipse with PDT and MakeGood

Tags: php, eclipse, mysqli, phpunit

Usually developing in C and Java, I don't manage to get PHPUnit tests to run in Eclipse properly.

I have Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1) installed with PDT 3.4.0 and MakeGood 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 15.04.

First I had the error

`PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class is not available. Fix...`

in MakeGood and trying to add the `PEAR [Environment]` user library to the build path to fix this repeatedly failed with

`Cannot create linked resource '/.org.eclipse.dltk.core.external.folders/.link1'`

That could be worked around by adding

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.dltk.USER_LIBRARY/PEAR"/>
```

to `.buildpath` in the Eclipse project folder.

Running a test then however failed with

`Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite' not found in [...] PHPUnitCollector.php on line 124`

So I created a `bootstrap.php`:

```
<?php 

include_once '/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
include_once '/usr/share/php/PHP/Token/Stream/Autoload.php';
```

and a `phpunit.xml`:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
</phpunit>
```

and set them as "Preload Script" and "XML Configuration File" in the MakeGood project properties.

It goes further, but now the test fails with

`Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found`

This is where I am lost now.

If I run the tests on the command line with

`phpunit --coverage-html coverage .`

they all run fine and also the HTML coverage reports are created.

In Eclipse preferences under PHP Executables I have selected `PHP CLI (Workspace Default)` with Location `/usr/bin/php`; the same php executable is used on the command line so I assume also the same php.ini is used... so I don't know why it fails in Eclipse but works on the command line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The information in your question was useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out - in Eclipse preferences under PHP Executables, I had to set `PHP 5.5.3 (CLI)` as default and make the following settings:

[image]

Important here is to have the field "PHP ini file (optional)" empty and the option "Use system default php.ini configuration" checked.

Now all tests are running in MakeGood.